# Conflicting type of structure in c

Tags: c, header-files

I am having a header file like this :

```
#ifndef my_data_h
#define my_data_h
struct Student{
    int GPA;
    int coursesCount;
    float tuitionFees;
};
struct employee{
    float salary;
    int yearOfService;
    int salaryLevel;
};
struct person{
    char firstName[11];
    char familyName[21];
    char telephone[11];
    int isStudent;
    struct Student student;
    struct employee employee;
};
#endif
```

Also I have student.h and student.c file for student.

student.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "data.h"
void getStudentData(struct Student);
```

student .c

```
#include "student.h"
#include "data.h"
void getStudentData(struct Student currentStudent){

}
```

Now I am having a .c file with main, in which I call something like this : getStudentData(myperson.student);

All the headers I included in this c file having main.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "student.h"
 #include "employee.h"
 #include "data.h"
```

But am getting error in student.c file that **Conflicting type of getStudentData**

How to solve it ?

Do I need to define a student structure in student.h also ?

Something like : **struct Student student;**

Comment: Show the relevant code excerpt and copy&paste the whole error message.

Comment: Where are defined the structs (in which file)? And when do you include it?

Comment: Note: the file student.h does not use any of the functions/definitions from stdio.h, so there is no need to #include <stdio.h> in the student.h file

Comment: a struct must be defined before using it.  (and you did not mention the name of the file that contains the struct definitions)  However, that file must be #include'd before any of the struct definitions are referenced.   this means before the function prototype in the student.h file

Comment: @user3629249 Check I had defined in data.h and also included t. but still same error

Comment: one more time...   The structs MUST be defined before using them.  so in student.c the order of the #includes must be: `#include "data.h"  #include "student.h"`

Answer (score 1):

in main.c

```
#include "header.h" // where structs are declared
#include "student.h"
void getStudentData(struct Student currentStudent){

}
```

or in  "student.h"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h" // where structs are declared
void getStudentData(struct Student);
```

Comment: i also recommend inclusion guard in all your includes.h as suggested by @Paul92

Comment: you have to include "data.h" first then student.h and employee.h

Comment: can you be more clear. why you don't post all main.c and student.c files?

Comment: please try to ask more helpful questions so that it can be helpfull for others

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of your problem is that you include your header file (the one which contains the struct definition) multiple times, even if you don't realise it. To avoid this, use an [inclusion guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in the header file:

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

// here goes the content of your header

#endif
```